# How can I know the name of the cache file created by NGINX?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, cache

Suppose I make a request, `https://example.com/path1/2?v=1`, and have enabled the proxy caching. How do I know the name of the cache file created by NGINX? The problem is, I want to delete the cache for a single URL and do not want to clear the complete NGINX cache. How can I do this?

[image]

These are the files inside my NGINX cache directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://devdocs.io/nginx/http/ngx_http_proxy_module#proxy_cache_path) cache file name is a result of applying MD5 function to a result of `proxy_cache_key` evaluation.

What you can try:

- check what's in `proxy_cache_key` in your config
- evaluate all the variables like `$host` and `$request_uri` manually for your target request
- md5-it (careful about the line ending character)
- see if you can find the resulting file and try to move it to other place

MD5 without `\n` at the end:

```
printf "example.com/path1/2?v=1" | md5sum
```

Comment: What would be the value of  proxy_cache_key  in `https://example.com/path1/2?v=1`?